# Delete the content of a field from all the node under a specific content type

Tags: entities, nodes, rules

What would be  the best approach (preferably with GUI) to delete the content of certain fields from certain content types.

I am thinking of using rules but I cant configure to do it.

Ny ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hi ARGO, you seem to have 13 questions with zero accepted answers.  Perhaps you could revisit your previous questions and accept some answers.

Answer (score 1):

Views Bulk Operations, using the "Modify entity values" action.

Comment: Hi Bojan, How can I use this with rules, upon importing data using feeds?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a little piece of code - just use [field_attach_update ()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7) function.

Here is very good article "[Saving node's fields without saving the node itself](http://blog.urbaninsight.com/2011/10/24/saving-nodes-fields-without-saving-node-itself)" that will help you.

Your code can be as follow:

```
$nids = db_query(
  'SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type in (:node_types)', 
  array(
    ':node_types' => array('TYPE1', 'TYPE2'),
  )
)->fetchCol();
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
  field_attach_presave('node', $node);
  field_attach_update('node', $node);
}
```